# jQuery event target/relatedTarget issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show DB data on the click of a heading element. The data is basically toggled on click. I had made a jQuery to handle the same. Being new to this i am unable to figure out the issue. Can anyone explain ?

On clicking view comments, i would like to see the comments for that particular picture.

jQuery:

```
<script>
   $('#headingone').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var b = $(event.target)
   b.find('.menu').toggle("slide")
  })
</script>
```

HTML:

```
            <h5 id="headingone" data-target=".menu">View Comments</h5>
            <div class="menu">
              {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
                <p id="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> said "{{i.text}}"</p>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to simply get the value of `data-target` attribute from the clicked heading element. This code should do it:

```js
  $('#headingone').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var b = $(this).attr("data-target");
   $(b).toggle("slide")
  })
```

```html
           
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <h5 id="headingone" data-target=".menu">View Comments</h5>
            <div class="menu">
              {% for i in item.piccomments.all %}
                <p id="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> said "{{i.text}}"</p>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This works ! thanks a lot. Only had to change the heading element id to class as mentioned by @empiric

Comment: he didn't ask you to change it from id to class

Comment: one more thing, on clicking view comments for picture triggers to open view comments for all pictures, any idea about that ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) here, which searches for child elements. 
In this scenario I would use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) to get the clicked element and traverse from there with either [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) or [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/):

```js
 $('#headingone').click(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.menu').toggle("slide");
 })
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 id="headingone" data-target=".menu">View Comments</h5>
<div class="menu">
  <p id="paratwo" style="margin:0px;"><strong>{{i.author}}</strong> said "{{i.text}}"</p>
</div>
```

If `#headingone` is not a link, button or form element you don't necessarily need [`event.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) here.

Comment: Hi , only issue is that it shows me the last comment of first in each picture

Comment: @GovindShah has each picture the element `#headingone` ? If so that is invalid html, IDs have to be unique so you have to use a class instead. If you still have issues it might help to include a full example of your rendered html